# When will the Model A be released?

Tags: pi-models

It is my understanding that only the Model B version of the Raspberry Pi is currently available.  What is the expected release date of the Model A version?

Comment: Why would u want the model A rather than B?

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX, lower cost - which is important if you need a bunch of them. lower power consumption - if you are powering from batteries or energy harvesting

Comment: What are you using them for? (just curious) is it worth the limitations?

Comment: Not having ethernet isn't a huge limitation if you add a USB wi-fi dongle.

Comment: @zoot is there a low power USB wifi dongle?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Quite a few: http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals#Working_USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters

Comment: @Zoot how do I determine which of the verified dongles which does not need more power than the Pi can provide?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Some of the entries on the chart indicate "Powered USB hub required", but it doesn't really indicate power draw very clearly for each entry.

Comment: @Zoot that might not even be enough.  Typically a USB port can provide 5W, but the Pi USB-ports cannot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first 12 Raspberry Pi Model A boards were auctioned off on eBay [during the Twelve Pis of Christmas](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/2828) in December of 2012, with the proceeds going to various charities.

[Adafruit](http://www.adafruit.com/blog/2013/04/29/new-product-raspberry-pi-model-a-256mb-ram/) started stocking the model A on April 29, 2013.

The Model A+ was [announced and made available for sale](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspberry-pi-model-a-plus-on-sale/) on November 10, 2014.

Answer (score 3):

A release date has not been announced for the model A yet. I would not expect to see the Model A available until production begins to match demand for the Model B. Based on the video from the Cambridge Raspberry Jam event held last weekend and the video interview of Eben it appears that the camera may be released before the model A.

http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/1576

This following was posted by Liz in the Raspberry Pi forums on June 13th

"I know that at least one manufacturer is planning on a September build; earlier if they can clear their backlog before then (but orders keep coming through at an ungodly rate, so realistically it’s likely to be September). The A will definitely be happening – we’re all contracted to make sure it goes ahead as planned – but the demand so far for the B has been so outlandish that a lot of plans have had to be changed or abandoned to get things working as well as they are at the moment. And we’re very aware that what we have at the moment isn’t optimal – yet."

http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/1389